# What is Domain and Range of Unary Function (Set Theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question in set theory that states:

```
Let X be the set {1, 2}
Let Y be the set {3, 4, 5, 6}
Let f be a function such that f: X->Y

n |f(n)
-------
1 |3
2 |4

What is the domain and range of f?
```

I'm a bit confused because my book describes that whenever we see `f: X->Y`, that `X->Y` represents the domain and range of our function `f`, yet the values provided in the table show that we don't use all of the values in the set Y for the output of function `f`.  So I don't know if the range of function is {3, 4, 5, 6} or {3, 4}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range should be $\{ 3, 4\}$ because they can be attained.

$\{3,4,5,6\}$ in this context is known as codomain. The Codomain is the set of values that could possibly come out. The Codomain is actually part of the definition of the function.

Comment: This is what I was leaning towards, but I wasn't entirely sure.  Also, I would guess that this is one-to-one, but not onto, as each output is obtained by only one input, but not all of the values of the codomain can be obtained.  Is this correct?

Comment: yes, it is one-to-one (injective) but not onto (surjective).

Comment: @joe_04_04 In modern mathematics (**especially in set theory**), the codomain is **not** part of the definition of the function. A function from naturals to positive reals is also a function from naturals to reals. And one would say "$f$ surjects onto $S$" instead of "$f$ is surjective".

Answer (score 1):

Range is the set of y values taken by $y=f(x)$ as $x$ runs over the domain.

In your case

$$ \text {Range =} \{3,4\}$$

because these are the only values taken by f(x).